# Entity Framework Cannot Create Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am building an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application using Entity Framework 4.1 with the Database First Approach.

I have just setup my solution with separate projects for the following:

1. UI - MVC app
2. Model - Class Library
3. POCOs - Class Library
4. Repositories - Class Library
5. Services - Class Library

I have set this up a few times before without any trouble, but now when I try to create a controller in my MVC app, I get the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Entityname'. An item with the same key has already been added.
```

This happens when I try to add any controller with an Entity for its Model class. I am stumped with this. I tried re-creating the model from the db and regenerated my POCO classes, but still this problem exists.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have more than project that has an Entity Model?  If so, you will need to make sure that the containers in each have different names.  I had this problem in a project where I had a few plug-in dlls that all added a single table to an existing database.  I copied and pasted one to another. At run time I got en error like this, until I changed the container name.

Comment: @Andras - I have several projects within my solution, one of which contains the model. Two of the other projects both reference the model. But I have done this before without any trouble.

Comment: yeah that's fine - one model is fine; I was talking about multiple projects with their own models.

Comment: I need to see some code examples if I am going to help you fix this.

Comment: @wayne - No code to show fella, all that was in the project was a newly created edmx file. The problem was that I renamed a Navigation property within an Entity to a name that already existed within another Entity. No compile error either, just when I tried to add a new controller. It was a tough one to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. When Entity Framework created my entity data model, some of the names it gave to the navigation properties were a bit meaningless. I therefore edited a couple of these properties, however, I ended up naming two different navigation properties, with the same type of association, the same name. Needless to say EF didn't like this. I renamed the offending navigation property. It was a tough one to fix as there were no compile errors from the model.